# How to layout a program?

Tags: c++, layout

I'm making an Arkanoid clone. This is the program layout I came up with:

```
source.cpp // few lines
     App class // has constants APP_WIDTH and APP_HEIGHT
         Ball class // has constant RADIUS
         Brick class
         Paddle class
```

Now I want to place the ball at the center of the window at the beginning of the game. Normally I would accomplish it like this:

```
Ball::Ball (App &app)
{
    circle.setPos(app->WINDOW_WIDTH/2-RADIUS/2,app->WINDOW_HEIGHT/2-RADIUS/2)
}
```

But the ball class doesn't know anything about the App!

Do I need to make `APP_WIDTH` and `APP_HEIGHT` global variables?

Or do I need to turn the current app layout upside down, so that Ball class has `#include "app.hpp"` statement?

**EDIT:** Or do I need to declare ball, brick and paddle classes inside the app class? But then where I define them? Inside the same app class? Then the header gets too big!

And maybe there are some good tutorials on program layout topic on the internet? I haven't found any...

**QUESTION 2:**
Why do classes need protected variables if "there is no reason that ball would know anything about app class"

Comment: what do you mean that the ball doesn't know anything about the app?  Is that not what you're passing in as a parameter?

Comment: App class includes ball class and then creates one. That's all. Ball doesn't have any access to the private members of app class.

Comment: For some reason, it feels like there's missing classes here.  My inner designer wants there to be a `Sprite` class, and a `Stage`.  The various parts would just move the sprites around on the stage like pieces on a game board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue seems to be that "Ball doesn't have any access to the private members of app class.", than maybe you want to make a getter.

A getter is a public method that returns the value of a private field.

If you do that, you can access the values of those members like so

```
circle.setPos(app->GetWidth()....
```

Your getter might look similar to the following

public int GetWidth()
{
    return this.APP_WIDTH;
}

Comment: Okay, I get it. But what about declaring ball, brick and paddle within the app class and making APP_WIDTH and APP_HEIGHT protected constants? Wouldn't that express the ownership structure more clearly? But then I get incomplete type errors when creating those subclasses in App, so I have to define them in the same App header and then it gets too big!

Comment: @MariusMacijauskas what about it?

Comment: Okay, I will ask it in in different way. Why do classes need protected variables if we use getter methods?

Comment: @MariusMacijauskas: `protected` basically declares an interface for subclasses.  It has very little to do with this.  But as for why have private variables...for example, note there's no `SetWidth()` function.  You can have variables that are actually *variable* (for instance, if the window can resize), without worrying about other code changing them willy-nilly.

Comment: @MariusMacijauskas  My `protected` variables are accessible by classes that inherit them.  it has little to do with getting and setting

Comment: Yes... I guess I just wanted to abuse the *protected* feature too much. I'll use getters and setters from now on.

Comment: @MariusMacijauskas: Getters and (particularly!) setters aren't that great either, from an OO perspective.  Their very existence is usually a step backwards from an object being responsible for its own state, and an indication that some other object is getting a little too intimate with it.  Only use getters and setters where they are less hairy than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for the game objects to know anything about the `App` they are part of. When it needs any information from `App`, it should receive them from `App` directly. This can happen either through setter-methods (recommended when properties can be changed by the App later, like the position of the ball) or in the constructor (recommended for things which don't change, like the positions of blocks).

Answer (score 0):

Ball should have a SetPosition(x,y) which app invokes with the above calculation. Internally, this SetPosition would set the circle like above, so ball knows nothing about app.